# vbs automatic script

Tags: windows, vbscript, automation

Is it possible to create a vbs script that call itself when a certain pc action is activated,lets say opening up  a browser?A replica would be someone opens up a browser,then the vbs listens to this activity and runs itself or calls another vbs script?

Answer (score 1):

Jimmy, if you want the code to be executed when a browser window is opened, consider this code :

```
Set obj0 = createobject("wscript.shell")
Dim Count
Count = 0
Do while count = 0
If obj0.appactivate("browserwindowtitle") then
-------do something----
----
----
Count = 1
Else
Wscript.sleep(10000)
Count = 0
End if
Loop
Set obj0 = nothing
```

The above code will check if the window having the title "browserwindowtitle" is open or not. If it is open, it will execute the desired action. If the window is not open, script will wait for 10 seconds and try again.

After writing the script go to control panel-> scheduled tasks and add the script as scheduled on startup. When you do this, the script will start executing when your PC turns on and will keep on checking if the browser window is open or not.

There will be easier ways to do this, others might be able to help.

Comment: dont want to use task scheduler as it is not available in guest mode...see my related question to this  `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740023/how-to-schedule-a-task-in-guest-account`

Comment: I don't know about that much. But maybe a workaround I can say. As part of the script we can constantly keep on checking the system time, and when it becomes 10am, the required action will execute. But here, we have to start the script manually before 10am. What task do you actually want to do at the particular time?

Comment: was thinking along those lines?just creating an app cant disclose the details for now!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give System Scheduler a try.

http://www.splinterware.com/products/wincron.htm